# Is there any example of dynamic module creation of type WirelessHost in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I need to create a dynamic module in omnet++, I found some code in the OMNeT Guide, I adapt it to satisfy what I need, but I got a problem with the MediumCanvasVisualizer, When I run the simulation I got the error below. May be an example could help me to notice where am I wrong.

When I tried to create a dynamic module of type StandardHost using the same steps, it works fine. The problem is when the module is of type WirelessHost.

Many thanks

> Cannot create medium visualization for 'Drones.clone.wlan[0].radio', 
>   because network node visualization is not found for 'Drones.clone' -- in 
>   module (inet::visualizer::MediumCanvasVisualizer) Drones.visualizer.canvasVisualizer.mediumVisualizer (id=21), at t=0.386488978053s, event #39

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using :

```
    cModuleType *moduleType = cModuleType::get("inet.node.inet.WirelessHost");
    cModule* module = moduleType->create("clone", this);
    module->finalizeParameters();
    module->buildInside();
    module->scheduleStart(simTime() + updateInterval);
```

Instead of :

```
    cModuleType *moduleType = cModuleType::get("inet.node.inet.WirelessHost");
    cModule *module = moduleType->createScheduleInit("clone", this);
```

Comment: I had to add module->callInitialize() in order to apply static configuration on the new node. But I got again the problem of the visualizer again. I have noticed that the callInitialize() function works fine. Until stage 1, it finds the network node visualizer (stage 0 and stage 1), but it crashes on stage 2.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/omnetpp/zeKCXjNaKlw
It solves my problem